# Starting a Linux desktop from CLI

Tags: linux, desktop

I can login to a lab Linux CLI, but have no further info on the install. Is there a generic command for starting a default DE/WM; I seem to recall "startx" would run a default X11 setup, but am looking to access a modern gui environment (if installed). Also, is there a default file explorer common to all distros?

Comment: The default file explorer is `coreutils`...

Comment: Thankyou all for your clarifications, I believe I have sufficient info to continue. PeteR 11010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startx` is still the standard way to run a desktop environment - graphical distros set up a desktop environment to be run when X is started. If it's not set up, you may want to look into creating [your own `.xinitrc`](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/.xinitrc).

[File managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_managers) are not distro specific; very few (if any) Linux programs are distro specific, since there's nothing *fundamentally* different between distros.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge xorg (stareted by `startx`) is the only GUI, what you might be referring to is **Desktop Enviroment**, that will vary from one computer to another.

Also almost nothing is common to all distros.

However you can expect bash to work more or les the same on all distros( depends on configuration files).

So commands:

`ls` will list contents of currently open directory

`dir` will display name of currently open

`cd` will move to directory mentioned after `cd` Example `cd /var/`